# About $\lim\dfrac{\sigma(n)}{n}$, where $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of divisor of $n$

Tags: limits, number-theory, divisor-sum

Denote $p\equiv 1 \mod 3$ is a prime number and $n$ is any number that divisible by $p$. Denote $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of divisor of $n$.
We know that $\dfrac{\sigma (n)}{n}>1$ and
$$\dfrac{\sigma (n)}{n}=\prod\limits_{p_i\mid n}\dfrac{p_i^{\alpha_i+1}-1}{p_i^{\alpha+1}-p_i^\alpha}<\prod_\limits{p_i\mid n\\p_i\neq p}\dfrac{p_i}{p_i-1}.\dfrac{p}{p-1}$$
When $p$ goes to infinitely then $n\rightarrow \infty$, we have $\dfrac{p}{p-1}\rightarrow 1$. But does
$\dfrac{\sigma (n)}{n}\rightarrow 1$ when $p\rightarrow \infty$, since we can't control other $p_i$ and the number of divisor of $n$ ($n$ is arbitrary and $p\mid n$).

Comment: $\prod_p \frac1{1-p^{-1}}=\lim_{s\to 1}\zeta(s)=\infty$

Comment: if $m=n!$ then $m+\frac{m}{2}+\frac{m}{3}+...+\frac{m}{n} \leq \sigma(m)$. As the harmonic series diverges then $\frac{\sigma(m)}{m}\rightarrow \infty$. (This can be used to prove that exists an infinitude of primes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit of $\dfrac {\sigma(n)}{n}$ does not exist, since for any multiple of $6p$, i.e. $n = 6pk$ we have

$$\frac {\sigma(n)}n > \frac {pk + 2pk + 3pk + 6pk}{6pk} = 2$$

while for $n = p^k$, we have $$\frac {\sigma (n)}n = \frac {p^{k+1} - 1}{p^k(p-1)  } < \frac {p^{k+1} + p^k(p-2)}{p^k(p-1)} = 2$$

Moreover, the ratio for prime powers tends to $1$, so for $n$ an arbitrary multiple of $p$, the limit of the abundancy index does not exist, no matter if $n \to\infty$ or $p \to \infty$.